# pod lib lint Error: Bundle identifier is missing

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

pod lib lint Error:

```
Bundle identifier is missing. App doesn't have a bundle identifier for the Release build configuration. Add a value for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in the build settings editor
```

Need to use real machine compiler So update validator.rb

before

```
when :ios
command += %w(CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=- -sdk iphonesimulator)
command += Fourflusher::SimControl.new.destination(:oldest, 'iOS', deployment_target)
```

after

```
when :ios
command += %w(-sdk iphoneos11.0 -destination=generic/iOS  ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ARCHS=armv7)
```

but will return error when pod lib lint

How do I need to configure the certificate for the compilation environment?

CocoaPods Environment

xcode9
cocoapods 1.3.1